# Rails iterate over only the persisted records associated to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have something like this in my `show` action:

```
def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @new_comment = @blog.comments.build
end
```

Now in the view I do two things:

1. I render the `_form.html.erb` for the `Comment` so that the user can add a comment to this blog
2. I want to be able to iterate over the **existing** comments for this blog in order to display them.

I am having problems with number **2**.  The issue is that as I iterate over the associated `comments` with this:

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

It is grabbing that `@new_comment` while iterating over the associated blogs.  How can I **exclude** that built-but-not-yet-persisted `@new_comment`?

It would be nice if something like `@blog.comments.each_with_id` worked, or even `@blog.comments.persisted.each`.  Ultimately I only want to iterate over the persisted `comments` associated to this `blog`.

I would prefer not to have to nest a conditional that asks if the comment is `persisted?`.  I'm hoping there is an iterator out there for my current situation that just grabs the persisted records.

Comment: in short, you don't want the newly created comments to be shown until refresh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you create the new comment without using the association to the blog instance? Then it won't show up when you iterate through `@blog.comments`.

```
def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @new_comment = Comment.new(blog: @blog)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

in your view loop, you can skip `if comment.new_record?`

```
<% @blog.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% next if comment.new_record? %>
```

EDIT per your comment:

if you dont want filter out during the iteration, you can reject new records before iterating. however, i wouldn't recommend this approach, as youre creating an entirely new array of records for little reason. Your performance shoundnt really take a hit assuming blogs dont have thousands of comments, but its still not a great practice.

```
<% @blog.comments.reject(&:new_record?).each do |comment| %>
```

if you truly want to separate the logic from the view and controller, you can make another variable entirely dedicated to blog comments, prior to building a new one, so that its not included during the iteration.

```
# controller
def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @current_comments = @blog.comments
  @new_comment = @blog.comments.build
end

#view
<% @current_comments.each do |comment| %>
```

for what its worth, i'd still recommend the first apprach

Comment: Indeed, that will work for sure. However, I'm not a big fan of the approach as it means the logic is then split between the controller and the view. I like my views to only receive the data they need to show, not having to do more filtering. but that's just a personal preference of course :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class method to your `Comment` model such as this:

```
def self.persisted
  reject { |comment| comment.new_record? }
end
```

Then call

```
@blog.comments.persisted
```

The downside is that it's not after this you don't have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` anymore and might break your scopes chaining. Make sure you're using it last in your `ActiveRecord` queries.