# Nil:nil class error on each loop when Form to build object loaded on page first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a form on a page that is building a “tip” for a “guide”.  Below the form, I am running an each loop over all the @guide.tips.  I keep getting an error as the each loop is loading the forms blank object as it sees it as a tip.  I’ve currently solved the problem by using jQuery to inject the form after page load, but there has to be a better solution.

**Each Loop on Guide.html.erb**

```
    <% if !@guide.tips.blank? %>
      <% @guide.tips.each do |tip| %>
        <div class="row mx-1">
          <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
            <div class="float-left">
              <%= image_tag avatar_url(tip.user), class: "float-left text-left align-middle rounded img-fluid mx-3", width: "30%" %>
              <p><%= tip.user.fullname %></p>
            </div>


            <div class="float-right mr-3">
              <%= link_to like_tip_path(tip), method: :put do %>
                <div class="fas fa-angle-up"></div>
                <%= tip.get_upvotes.size %>
              <% end %><br/>

              <%= link_to dislike_tip_path(tip), method: :put do %>
                <div class="fas fa-angle-down"></div>
                <%= tip.get_downvotes.size %>
              <% end %>
            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 ml-3">
            <h6><%= tip.title %> -<span class="ml-1"><small><%= tip.created_at.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p")%></small></span></h6>

            <%= tip.tip %>
          </div>
        </div><hr/>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**Tips_Controller.rb**

```
      def new
        @guide = Guide.find(params[:guide_id])
        @tip = Tip.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @guide = Guide.find(params[:guide_id])
        params[:tip][:user_id] = current_user.id
        @tip = @guide.tips.create!(tip_params)
        redirect_to guide_path(@guide)
      end
```

**Tip Form Partial**

```
    <%= form_for([@guide, @guide.tips.build]) do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p class="text-left">Tip Title</p>
          <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Enter Title", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-2">
          <p class="text-left">Your Tip</p>
          <%= f.text_area :tip, placeholder:"What's your tip for this travel guide?", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution `that does not separate the logic` between the controller and the view and cleans up your empty array statement for your loop

**Each Loop on Guide.html.erb**

```
  <% @guide.tips.each do |tip| %>
    <div class="row mx-1">
      <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
        <div class="float-left">
          <%= image_tag avatar_url(tip.user), class: "float-left text-left align-middle rounded img-fluid mx-3", width: "30%" %>
          <p><%= tip.user.fullname %></p>
        </div>


        <div class="float-right mr-3">
          <%= link_to like_tip_path(tip), method: :put do %>
            <div class="fas fa-angle-up"></div>
            <%= tip.get_upvotes.size %>
          <% end %><br/>

          <%= link_to dislike_tip_path(tip), method: :put do %>
            <div class="fas fa-angle-down"></div>
            <%= tip.get_downvotes.size %>
          <% end %>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 ml-3">
        <h6><%= tip.title %> -<span class="ml-1"><small><%= tip.created_at.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p")%></small></span></h6>

        <%= tip.tip %>
      </div>
    </div><hr/>
  <% end  unless @guide.tips.blank? %>
```

**Tip Form Partial**

By creating the Tip from outside the association (i.e. not using build), it will not be loaded into the class variable's children

```
<%= form_for([@guide, Tip.new(guide: @guide)]) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p class="text-left">Tip Title</p>
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Enter Title", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-2">
      <p class="text-left">Your Tip</p>
      <%= f.text_area :tip, placeholder:"What's your tip for this travel guide?", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[Another Example / Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754188/rails-iterate-over-only-the-persisted-records-associated-to-an-object)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and seems like a great way to achieve what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Using the structure you already have you could do:

`<% if @guide.tips.count > 1 %>` (assuming this will always be shown with an empty "build" tip)

or you can use:

`<% next unless tip.persisted? %>`

inside the loop, before the actual form.

You also don't need the `blank?` check as an `.each` on an empty enumerator simply won't execute the block, and as long as there's a has_many relationship between guide and tips it will always yield a collection proxy.

I would write it as:

`<% @guide.tips.each do |tip| %>
  <% next unless tip.persisted? %>
  <div class="row mx-1">
  <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
  ...
<% end %>`